# I want to change jquery function to pure javascript function multiple select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$('#publisher').on('change', function(e) {
  let selector = $(this).val();
  $("#site > option").hide();
  $("#site > option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('pub') == selector
  }).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Publisher
</p>
<select id="publisher" name="publisher">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="176253">(176253) 1010TIRES.COM INC.</option>
  <option value="176278">(176278) Bikeland Media</option>
  <option value="176282">(176282) Bilden Enterprises, Inc.</option>
  <option value="176254">(176254) 4GE Media Group</option>
  <option value="176292">(176292) BROtocross.com</option>
</select>
<p>
  Site
</p>
<select id="site" name="site">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="321231" data-pub="176253">(321231) 1010TIRES.COM</option>
  <option value="321235" data-pub="176278">(176278) Bikeland</option>
  <option value="321240" data-pub="176278">(176278) DragList</option>
  <option value="321248" data-pub="176278">(176278) Race-Dezert.com</option>
  <option value="321254" data-pub="176278">(176278) BROtocross</option>
  <option value="321261" data-pub="176282">(176282) Chronic MX | Motocross For Life</option>
  <option value="321267" data-pub="176282">(176282) CompetitionPlus.com</option>
  <option value="321269" data-pub="176254">(176254) DuneGuide.com</option>
  <option value="321285" data-pub="176254">(176254) 4x4wire.com</option>
  <option value="321291" data-pub="176254">(176254) FORDMUSCLE MAGAZINE</option>
  <option value="321301" data-pub="176292">(176292) Hayabusa Owners Group</option>
</select>
```

I want this jquery code converted to pure JavaScript this UI mechanism is ok.
this code is  work I want to only pure JavaScript in this jquery code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not a good question, it is pretty much asking some one to code for you, which is not stack overflow.

Only thing worth mentioning here is u can get all elements using `document.querySelectorAll('#site > option')` and then loop them.

Please check this

```js
var publisherElement = document.getElementById('publisher');
  publisherElement.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
     let options = document.querySelectorAll('#site > option');

     for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
     if (options[i].getAttribute('data-pub') == event.target.value) {
         options[i].style.display = 'block';
     } else {
         options[i].style.display = 'none';
     }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
 Publisher
</p>
<select id="publisher" name="publisher"><option value="">Please Select</option><option value="176253">(176253) 1010TIRES.COM INC.</option>
<option value="176278">(176278) Bikeland Media</option>
<option value="176282">(176282) Bilden Enterprises, Inc.</option>
<option value="176254">(176254) 4GE Media Group</option>
<option value="176292">(176292) BROtocross.com</option>
</select>
<p>
Site
</p>
  <select id="site" name="site">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="321231" data-pub="176253">(321231) 1010TIRES.COM</option>
<option value="321235" data-pub="176278">(176278) Bikeland</option>
<option value="321240" data-pub="176278">(176278) DragList</option>
<option value="321248" data-pub="176278">(176278) Race-Dezert.com</option>
<option value="321254" data-pub="176278">(176278) BROtocross</option>
<option value="321261" data-pub="176282">(176282) Chronic MX | Motocross For Life</option>
<option value="321267" data-pub="176282">(176282) CompetitionPlus.com</option>
<option value="321269" data-pub="176254">(176254) DuneGuide.com</option>
<option value="321285" data-pub="176254">(176254) 4x4wire.com</option>
<option value="321291" data-pub="176254">(176254) FORDMUSCLE MAGAZINE</option>
<option value="321301" data-pub="176292">(176292) Hayabusa Owners Group</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below snippet, here initially we set options for the second select as `display:none`, on change event of the first select, we use a loop and add `.show` to the options.

```js
const el = document.getElementById('publisher');
const site = document.getElementById('site');
const options = site.options;
el.addEventListener('change', function() {
  let selector = event.target.value;
  Array.from(site.children).forEach(option => {
    if (option.dataset.pub === selector) {
      option.classList.add('show')
    } else {
      option.classList.remove('show');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.show {
  display: block!important;
}

#site option {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Publisher
</p>
<select id="publisher" name="publisher">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="176253">(176253) 1010TIRES.COM INC.</option>
  <option value="176278">(176278) Bikeland Media</option>
  <option value="176282">(176282) Bilden Enterprises, Inc.</option>
  <option value="176254">(176254) 4GE Media Group</option>
  <option value="176292">(176292) BROtocross.com</option>
</select>
<p>
  Site
</p>
<select id="site" name="site">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="321231" data-pub="176253">(321231) 1010TIRES.COM</option>
  <option value="321235" data-pub="176278">(176278) Bikeland</option>
  <option value="321240" data-pub="176278">(176278) DragList</option>
  <option value="321248" data-pub="176278">(176278) Race-Dezert.com</option>
  <option value="321254" data-pub="176278">(176278) BROtocross</option>
  <option value="321261" data-pub="176282">(176282) Chronic MX | Motocross For Life</option>
  <option value="321267" data-pub="176282">(176282) CompetitionPlus.com</option>
  <option value="321269" data-pub="176254">(176254) DuneGuide.com</option>
  <option value="321285" data-pub="176254">(176254) 4x4wire.com</option>
  <option value="321291" data-pub="176254">(176254) FORDMUSCLE MAGAZINE</option>
  <option value="321301" data-pub="176292">(176292) Hayabusa Owners Group</option>
</select>
```